# How to graph the numeric data in cacti

Tags: snmp, cacti

I have custom applications for that I want to graphs the stats. Here is my requirement. I wrote a bash script which give me a numeric value and I am running that script from cron. Now I want that numeric data should be graphed via cacti using SNMP. I know its possible but not sure how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your cron call rrdtool directly and make an RRD. It won't show in Cacti but it will make a graph. If you want it in Cacti, you would want to add some script to snmpd.conf that calls the script so Cacti can poll it.

Comment: I got it working, actually you have to run your script via snmp and it should be done via /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file. In this file you need to run your script and associate the result to an OID. Below is the entry in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf 

sh sh .1.3.6.1.4.1.26145.2.1 UsedPorts
/usr/local/scripts/get_used_ports.sh

in some of the snmp client its syntax start from exec command rest is same.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to involve SNMP. Create a *Data Input Method* and use "Script/Command" as the *Input Type*, specifying the path your script.

Here's the [relevant documentation page](http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/data_input_methods.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look at gnuplot.